# cdt1.8.1 compile issue

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt

error encountered when compile the contracts with cdt 1.8.1, any idea?

```
/usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.8.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/boost/pfr/detail/core17_generated.hpp:38:9: error:
type 'swaps_row' decomposes into 2 elements, but only 1 names were provided
auto& [a] = val;
^
/usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.8.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/boost/pfr/detail/core17_generated.hpp:1032:30: note:
in instantiation of function template specialization
'boost::pfr::detail::tie_as_tuple<swaps_row>' requested here
return boost::pfr::detail::tie_as_tuple(val, fields_count_tag{});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add EOSLIB_SERIALIZE macro manually.

```
struct swaps_row {
  TYPE a;
  TYPE b;
  TYPE c;

  uint64_t primary_key() const { return XXX; }

  EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(swaps_row, (a)(b)(c)) // Like this!
};
```